# How do I change the font color in VB6?

Tags: vb6, fonts, colors

I have some code that displays values from a record set.  If the value is less than 8000, I wish to change the color of the displayed text.  I tried this:

```
If (recordset(1).Value) < 80000 Then
    font.color = &HFFEFEF
End If
```

But it didn't work.  How do I do it?

Comment: what does font points to? and which control do you use to display the values in the recordset?

Comment: @Gopal, if Raven's answer corrected your problem please mark it as the answer (checkmark beneath the voting area)

Comment: Less than 8000 or 80000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify how you are displaying the information, but if you're using a TextBox, you would changed the text color via the ForeColor property

```
Text1.ForeColor = &HFFEFEF
```

Answer (score 6):

Addon to raven's answer.

You can also use:

```
Text1.ForeColor = vbBlack

'vbBlack, vbWhite, vbBlue, vbRed, vbGreen, vbYellow, vbMagenta, vbCyan
```

and

```
Text1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0 ) 'red

0, 0, 0 - black
255, 255, 255 - white
255, 0, 0 - red
0, 255, 0 - green
0, 0, 255 - blue
255, 255, 0 - yellow
0, 255, 255 - cyan
255, 0, 255 - magenta
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the forecolor of the textbox/label inside each conditions may do the trick. For example I want to input an integer and I want to know if the integer I've entered is ODD or EVEN.

The deal is:
If the integer is an ODD, it will display as a RED text in the label,
else if it is EVEN, it will display as blue in the label.

Take this as an example:

> Input number: text1
>   Output: label1

Code:

```
 if (val(text1) mod 2) = 1 then
      label1 = "ODD"
      label1.Forecolor = vbRed
 else
      label1 = "EVEN"
      label1.Forecolor = vbBlue
 end if
```

*mod is a modulo operator function used to take the remainder of the text1 divided by 2?